# Is it possible to debug SQLServer stored procedure using JetBrains DataGrip?

Tags: sql-server, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I'm debugging SQLServer sp using SMSS, but interested debugging using DataGrip. Anyone can help?

Comment: It's not implement yet. Follow the issue [DBE-9404](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-9404) to track progress.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not possible yet in DataGrip https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-9404

Answer (score -2):

I've just published a plugin for that purpose.
Not that the plugin is in early stage of development.
Hope some developers join the project.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18419-postgresql-debugger

Comment: The answer is related to PostgreSQL, while the question is about MS SQL Server.